# Refactoring multiple render in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, refactoring, jbuilder

In my rails controller, I have to check after getting `@group` with `before_action` that this group is not *system*.

But I have lot's of repetition in my controller. I've tried to turn into a separate method but I get the classic :

```
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

Here is a part of my code without the separate method who give me the error.

```
def destroy
  if @group.is_system?
    render json: { errors: 'You can\'t delete a group system' }, status: 403
    return
  end

  ...
end

def update
  if params[:group] && !params[:group].empty?
    if @group.is_system?
      render json: { errors: 'You can\'t edit a group system' }, status: 403
      return
    end

    ...

  else
    render json: { errors: 'Missing correct parameters' }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

.....
```

Comment: Please add the `callback('before_action')` part, not very clear of what you're doing.

Comment: I confirm you should add the `before_action` you used since I dont see why you'd have the error message: `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return"`

Comment: my before_action only find do begin
      @group = current_store.groups.find(params[:group_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      render_404
      return
    end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have in a parent controller:

```
def render_errors(errors, status)
  render json: { errors: Array(errors) }, status: status
end

def render_403(errors)
  render_errors(errors, 403)
end

def render_422(errors)
  render_errors(errors, 422)
end
```

then in your action:

```
before_action :check_system

def check_system      
  # I assume you already defined @group
  render_403('You can\'t delete a group system') if @group.is_system?
end
```

Notice I changed a bit of your code: having `errors` key which is only a string is very misleading, should be an array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer apneadiving. Will try it.

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks for the tips for the errors